# How to fetch the first successful completed Future?

Tags: scala, promise, future

## Problem

I would like to make two parallel executions with the help of futures. One queries the cache and the another one the database. The caller should return the first **successful** completed future or the database future.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class UserServiceImpl(
    private val cacheRepository: CacheRepository, 
    private val databaseRepository: DatabaseRepository
)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends UserService {

    override def getUserByName(username: String): Future[User] = {
        val cacheFuture: Future[User] = Future {
            cacheRepository.getUser(username)
        }
        val databaseFuture: Future[User] = Future {
            databaseRepository.getUser(username)
        }

        // now return the first successful finished Future[User] or the databaseFuture if completed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Future.find()` might be what you want. According to [the docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#find%5BT%5D(futures:scala.collection.immutable.Iterable%5Bscala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D%5D)(p:T=%3EBoolean)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BOption%5BT%5D%5D) it returns, *"the first Future with a result that matches the predicate"*, and also,  *"...failed Futures will be ignored."* So all you need is a predicate that holds **true** for any returned `User`.

If `User` were a `String`, for example, then the following should work.

```
Future.find(List(cacheFuture,databaseFuture))(_.nonEmpty)
```

Note that this returns a `Future[Option[User]]` in case no `User` is found.